# How to count all the results and count specific in the same query - MySql

Tags: mysql

I need to count all `FirstExtracted` for a specific date, and I need to count all `LastExtracted` for the same date. So, for today, I would need all the `FirstExtracted` and `LastExtracted`that equal `2012-10-24`.

Here is what I have so far but it doesnt bring up `LastExtracted`. It outputs `LastExtracted` as same count as `FirstExtracted`:

```
(SELECT LastExtracted,FirstExtracted,
COUNT(FirstExtracted) AS FirstCount,
COUNT(LastExtracted) AS LastCount,
DATE_FORMAT(`LastExtracted`,'%Y-%m-%d') AS Lastdate,
DATE_FORMAT(`FirstExtracted`,'%Y-%m-%d') AS Firstdate 
FROM results
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(`FirstExtracted`,'%Y-%m-%d') = DATE_FORMAT(`LastExtracted`,'%Y-%m-%d'))
UNION ALL
(SELECT LastExtracted,FirstExtracted,
COUNT(FirstExtracted) AS FirstCount,
COUNT(LastExtracted) AS LastCount,
DATE_FORMAT(`LastExtracted`,'%Y-%m-%d') AS Lastdate,
DATE_FORMAT(`FirstExtracted`,'%Y-%m-%d') AS Firstdate 
FROM results
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(`FirstExtracted`,'%Y-%m-%d') = DATE_FORMAT(`LastExtracted`,'%Y-%m-%d') GROUP BY Firstdate) 
ORDER BY Firstdate DESC
LIMIT 20
```

Maybe I should use inner join?

UPDATE:
so using your query i made some changes to make it do something else for me now. if you look at this page i put the query up

semesterold.com/code2.html

I want to count all titles and GROUP BY artist. it would be an array. then i want the sub queries to count by searchtype that match by the artists. so if the db has akon, rihanna, chris brown. i want it to count how many titles each artist has, say akon has 100. then i want to display the number of titles and then count how many of those 100 titles are google, bing, site specific for akon and etc.

Comment: What is the table definition?

Comment: what do you mean by table definition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use the union to get the two results (FirstExtracted and LastExtracted) separately and then merge them using a subquery.

```
SELECT
    sub.date, sum(sub.FirstCount) AS FirstCount,
    sum(sub.LastCount) AS LastCount 
  FROM (
      SELECT
          DATE_FORMAT(`FirstExtracted`,'%Y-%m-%d') AS date,
          COUNT(FirstExtracted) AS FirstCount, 0 AS LastCount
        FROM results
        GROUP BY date
      UNION ALL
        SELECT
            DATE_FORMAT(`LastExtracted`,'%Y-%m-%d'),
            0, COUNT(LastExtracted)
          FROM results
          GROUP BY date
    ) AS sub 
    GROUP BY sub.date
```

Say you have 220 entries extracted today for the first time and 292 that were most recently extracted today. Among entries for other dates, this would give you:

```
+------------+------------+-----------+
| date       | FirstCount | LastCount |
+------------+------------+-----------+
| 2012-10-24 |        220 |       292 |
+------------+------------+-----------+
```

**Update** The `UNION` alone will give you the following results. Notice the zero placeholders.

```
+------------+------------+-----------+
| date       | FirstCount | LastCount |
+------------+------------+-----------+
| 2012-10-24 |        220 |         0 |
+------------+------------+-----------+
| 2012-10-24 |          0 |       292 |
+------------+------------+-----------+
```

Comment: This worked perfectly!! can you please explain how you did this and what the zeros are for? I'm very interested in understanding it.

Comment: The first query in the `UNION` selects only the counts of `FirstExtracted` for a given date. The second grabs the `LastExtracted` count for a given date. Both use zeros as placeholders for the other. Then the outer query merges the two into one row by date, so 220 + 0, and 0 + 292 which gives you the result seen above.

Comment: but in the second part you have Select DATE_FORMAT(xx), 0, COUNT(LastExtracted) why is there a zero? also when you put sub.date that means its calling date from the union queries so you can select variables that are in the union queries before they are run? i thought sql went in order. if you call sub.date and sum(sub.FirstCount) they haven't been defined yet until after the FROM. This is all very interesting.

Comment: Please see my update as to why there is a zero. The order of SQL isn't really from left to right. The basic order of operations for SQL is `FROM`, `WHERE`, `SELECT`. Think of it as going to the grocery store to buy your favorite brand of bread. Written in SQL, it would be `SELECT product FROM groceryStore WHERE type="bread" AND brand="MyBrand"`. The first thing you do is go to the store (`FROM`). Next, you look for MyBrand bread (`WHERE`), and then, lastly you put the product in your cart (`SELECT`).

Comment: wow, well put! I have one other question. In MySQL, am I allowed to call certain variables that are defined in the sub query but in another sub query?

Comment: @Dev-Ria Please start by looking around Stack Overflow for other questions about passing parameters to subqueries as those answers may solve your question as well. If your search comes up empty and nothing works, then feel free to open another question. We wouldn't want to turn one question into a continuous thread of questions, as that would be more confusing than helpful to others.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest adding `DISTINCT` in your query:

```
(SELECT LastExtracted,FirstExtracted,
COUNT(DISTINCT FirstExtracted) AS FirstCount,
COUNT(DISTINCT LastExtracted) AS LastCount,
DATE_FORMAT(`LastExtracted`,'%Y-%m-%d') AS Lastdate,
DATE_FORMAT(`FirstExtracted`,'%Y-%m-%d') AS Firstdate 
FROM results
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(`FirstExtracted`,'%Y-%m-%d') = DATE_FORMAT(`LastExtracted`,'%Y-%m-%d'))
UNION ALL
(SELECT LastExtracted,FirstExtracted,
COUNT(DISTINCT FirstExtracted) AS FirstCount,
COUNT(DISTINCT LastExtracted) AS LastCount,
DATE_FORMAT(`LastExtracted`,'%Y-%m-%d') AS Lastdate,
DATE_FORMAT(`FirstExtracted`,'%Y-%m-%d') AS Firstdate 
FROM results
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(`FirstExtracted`,'%Y-%m-%d') = DATE_FORMAT(`LastExtracted`,'%Y-%m-%d') GROUP BY Firstdate) 
ORDER BY Firstdate DESC
LIMIT 20
```

Comment: How would this help? Just curious, because it seems like the asker wants to add up all of the entries extracted for the first or last time on the same date whilst keeping first and last separate. Using `DISTINCT` makes it look like you're counting only the ones on different dates rather than the same date.